# How to align html text in panel Ext js

Tags: extjs6-classic

What is the proper way to align ExtJs panel. I have tried textAlign property but it doesn't work.

This is my code

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    title:'Hello World',
    width:350,
    html:'First Ext Program',
    render:'division',
})
```

If I run this, I can get a pretty panel with the text which is "First Ext Program". By default it is left align but I want to align it to the center or right. Can you guys please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the config `bodyStyle`.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-bodyStyle

This should do the trick (Tested in ExtJs 6.0.1 Classic-Toolkit):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    title:'Hello World',
    width:350,
    html:'First Ext Program',
    render:'division',
    bodyStyle: 'text-align: center;'
})
```

Comment: Wow....Thank you so much it's really working ....Could you tell where can i find these kind of tricky things??And thanks once again

Comment: In regards to the styling of Components in ExtJs. And I'm not saying that this will help you with every component or you will always get the nicest solution but everything comes with experience.
Let's say you want to align your inner html in the Panel.
Open the documentation. Now there are 3 things you can search for:
- A property with align that does the trick directly
- A style property (e.g. style, bodyStyle > They are all documented) to do inline styling for your component
- A cls property (e.g. cls, bodyCls) to add css classes

Comment: your words are really helpful thank you so much for that......